# Yahoo finance symbol suggest no longer working?

Tags: yfinance

```py
result = requests.get('http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=tesla&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback').json()
result
```

When I run the python code above, I get `<Response [404]>`, does anyone know why that might be? I am worried this API no longer works even though I saw posts from just a year ago talking about it working.

Comment: Could be the website is down

Answer (score 4):

If it's not documented, you can't rely on it working. The only (relatively) sure bet is to use some official API instead (which usually comes at a cost).

That said, if you want to continue using undocumented stuff (with the same risk of it getting shut down or you getting blocked any day), give this a try:

https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search?q=tesla

(I looked at what https://finance.yahoo.com/ uses.)

This delivers results like these:

```json
{
  "explains": [],
  "count": 15,
  "quotes": [
    {
      "exchange": "NMS",
      "shortname": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "quoteType": "EQUITY",
      "symbol": "TSLA",
      "index": "quotes",
      "score": 2048451,
      "typeDisp": "Equity",
      "longname": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "exchDisp": "NASDAQ",
      "isYahooFinance": true
    },
    {
      "exchange": "NEO",
      "shortname": "TESLA, INC. CDR (CAD HEDGED)",
      "quoteType": "EQUITY",
      "symbol": "TSLA.NE",
      "index": "quotes",
      "score": 24083,
      "typeDisp": "Equity",
      "longname": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "exchDisp": "NEO",
      "isYahooFinance": true
    },
    // ...
  ],
  "news": [
    // Also delivers news here...
  ],
  // Some meta stuff here
}
```

Use at your own risk.